# How to insert data without auto incrementing ID using SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I need to insert one value into a table based on an auto incremented ID, for example the ID = 7 and I want to insert "this" into a column based on the ID "7".

I basically want to do this, but am not sure how to do it without auto incrementing the ID.

```
INSERT INTO table (tableData) VALUES (12345) 
FROM table
WHERE ID = 7
```

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO table (tableData) 
SELECT ID FROM table
WHERE ID  7
```

But that just inserts the number 7 into the column and auto increments the table. Is there a way to insert a value based on the ID without auto-incrementing another row?

Thanks in advance

(SOLVED)

I figured out the problem. All I need to do was use UPDATE instead of INSERT so I used

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET columnname ="something" 
WHERE ID = "7"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. All I need to do was use UPDATE instead of INSERT so I used

```
 UPDATE tablename 
 SET column="something" 
 WHERE ID = "7"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column can be nullable:

```
INSERT INTO tableData (id)
VALUES (7)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want to be able to insert a value into a column into row 7. So it would be more like INSERT INTO tabledata (somecolumn) VALUES (43543) FROM tabledata WHERE ID = 7